# Find all index values for string t in string s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, substring

Input:

```
s = "ADOBECODEBANC"
t = "ABC"
```

Output:

```
{A:[0,10] , B:[3.9], C:[5,12]}
```

Do we have any in built function ?

Comment: `{c: [i for i, d in enumerate(s) if c == d] for c in t}`

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin function, but you can use `enumerate()` for the task:

```py
s = "ADOBECODEBANC"
t = "ABC"

out = {}
for i, ch in enumerate(s):
    if ch in t:
        out.setdefault(ch, []).append(i)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'A': [0, 10], 'B': [3, 9], 'C': [5, 12]}
```

Comment: Is this the only solution?

Comment: @NITHISHREDDYMINUPURI Of course not, you can use `re` module, or don't use `enumerate()` and use a counter variable instead....

Comment: @NITHISHREDDYMINUPURI If you are looking for a one-liner, the comment by Samwise can be a nice alternative. But that one is about 40% slower than this one.